# Tricky integral limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{(1-t)^{n+1}} dt=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have $x \in (-1,1)$ and I need to show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{(1-t)^{n+1}} dt=0$$
How do I even start?

The context to this problem is the remainder of the Taylor series for $\ln{(1-x)}$. If there is a way to show that the Taylor series is identical to the function in $(-1,1)$ without taking this limit: I'm also interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let be $0 < x < 1$. The function
$$t\longmapsto\frac{x - t}{1 - t}$$
is decreasing in $[0,x]$ (why?), so
$$t\in[0,x]\implies 0\le\frac{x - t}{1 - t}\le x
\implies
0 \le \frac{(x - t)^n}{(1 - t)^{n+1}}\le\frac{x^n}{1 - x},$$
And
$$
0\le\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{(1-t)^{n+1}}\,dt\le
\frac{x^{n+1}}{1 - x}.
$$
When $-1 < x < 0$, the bounding is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $t=xs$ to see that your integral equals
$$x^{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-s)^{n}}{(1-xs)^{n+1}}\,ds.$$

This is bounded above by

$$\tag 1\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-s)^{n}}{(1-xs)^{n}}\,ds = \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\int_0^1 \left (\frac{1-s}{1-xs}\right )^n\,ds.$$

The last integrand is $\le 1$ and thus $(1)$ is bounded above by $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\cdot1 \to 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y= \frac{x-t}{1-t}\in (0,x)$ and recognize $\lim_{n \to \infty}  y^{n}=0$ to obtain

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{(1-t)^{n+1}} dt
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^x \frac{y^{n}}{1-y} dy
= \int_0^x \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty}  y^{n}}{1-y} dy=0
$$

Comment: Why am I allowed to put the limit in the integrant?

Comment: @FabioN - the integral $\int_0^x \frac{y^{n}}{1-y} dy$ converges for $x\in(-1,1)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. In your third step, you switch the limit into the integral and I don't understand why the equality still holds.

Comment: @FabioN, *uniform* convergence of the integrand in $[0,x]$ is important. Alternatively, the integral can be explicitly bound.

Comment: @FabioN - the switch is allowed if the integral converges